# How to keep my old number in WhatsApp having the old SIM deactivated?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have a new phone number and a new phone, but I want to keep my old number to use in WhatsApp but I don't have that SIM card anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a deactivated SIM card on the phone, my guess is that you should still be able to use your WhatsApp through WiFi. But if you have taken out the SIM, it is not more possible as the new SIM will require an SMS-based validation. Better to port your number and then you can use it on WhatsApp.